# Nginx proxy with Google OAuth 2.0

Tags: nginx, meteor, proxy, google-oauth

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server and I have a meteor application that runs at `localhost:3000` on this server. The public FQDN of my server is `sub.example.com`. The meteor application uses Google OAuth 2.0, I have the following configured in the Google API Console:

```
URI REDIRECTION  
http://sub.example.com/_oauth/google
http://sub.example.com/_oauth/google?close
 ORIGINES JAVASCRIPT 
http://sub.example.com
```

My Nginx config file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name sub.example.com www.sub.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

The proxy works and I can access my meteor application when I go to `sub.example.com`. But when in this application I try to use Google OAuth 2.0, a pop up opens as it should and I get :

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google?close did not match a registered redirect URI.
```

I have played with the header in the nginx config file with no luck.

I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: you are sending the request from http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google?close  put that in the redirect uri.  on cloud console.

Comment: As far as I understand this is not working because the user browser doesn't have access to the server's localhost. But if the meteor application is on my laptop I can do that and it's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should rewrite the `Location` headers that your backend sends to Nginx described in http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_redirect, so:

```
proxy_redirect http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google http://sub.example.com/_oauth/google;
```

the other option, that would work for popup-style login as well is to set the `ROOT_URL` environment variable for Meteor at startup as follows:

```
ROOT_URL="http://sub.example.com" PORT=3000 node main.js
```

Comment: 'export ROOT_URL="http://sub.example.com"' makes it right for me, I even get why. Just adding the proxy_redirect did not. Thank you Hans Z..

Comment: yeah, the proxy_redirect would work for non-popup/full-browser-redirect environments

Comment: Great answer! Saved me an hour or two! For comprehensive set of environment variables used by meteor see: http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Environment_Variables