# NodeJS oAuth Google Nginx Proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx, oauth, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a problem with oAuth redirect under nginx proxy. I have the google social login button on my website and locally it works well. When i upload my project online and i put it under nginx proxy it doesn't work anymore. When i click login the browser redirects me to localhost:3000/auth/google/callback instead of mywebpage.com/auth/google/callback telling me that that page doesn't exist.
I am aware of this question: [Nginx proxy with Google OAuth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674550/nginx-proxy-with-google-oauth-2-0) and i tried to use the fixes they suggest but they didn't work because i don't run Meteor but NodeJS on Express with a Nginx Proxy.
The second solution they suggest is to use proxy_redirect but it doesn't seem to work. I have an oAuth with google but every time i click it(it's a browser redirect, not a popup) it redirects me to localhost:3000 which is the url behind the proxy. 
I tried every possible configuration of proxy_redirect but it always redirects me there. This is my proxy part in nginx:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:3000 https://mywebsite.com;
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting this inside a server block?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Try removing the proxy_redirect too. And I don't think you can proxy from http to https or https to http. As far as I know the protocol needs to remain the same.